# Scraping sub div under div class

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to **scrape** amazon, the concept is I search for a product in search-box and from results I count the rank of occurance of product in search page using product's unique ASIN. So I have able to scrape the main div but I'm unable to scrape sub-divs under main div which contains search results. [image: main div containing sub divs]

In the picture you can see , main div class which has sub divs containing unique ASIN no. How can I iterate over sub divs, I have tried `response.xpath('//div[@class="s-main-slot s-result-list s-search-results sg-row"]')` and `response.css('.s-main-slot,.s-result-list,.s-search-results,.sg-row').extract()` but both seem to have some missing data and I can't iterate over them. How can I iterate over sub divs? I'm fairly new to scrappy any help would be really appreciated , thanks.

Answer (score 1):

with css which I'm more familiar with you can do it like this.

```
results = response.css('div.s-search-results > div[data-asin]::attr(data-asin)').getall()
for asin in results:
    print(result)
```

Explaination

`div.s-search-results` target outer div. `> div[data-asin]` targets divs directly inside the outer div that has the "data-asin" attribute. `::attr('data-asin')` reads attribute 'asin'. You can change that last part if you want to extract other information.